# How to create a mpfr array?

Tags: c, mpfr

I searched for some hours on internet and through the docs, but I didn't see mention to create an array/list of MPFR (GMP) objects.
I am using C, not C++.
I you would please help me, I'd only need to get and set values from and to that array, and perhaps a "malloc" once..

Comment: `mpfr_t your_array[array_size]`? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The thing is, there's a huge propability i'd need to "malloc" the array dynamically.

Comment: `mpfr_t *your_array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(*your_array))`?

Comment: But how do I get value at index 0 (for example) ? When I try to display it, the program stops responding.. event though the displaying works fine for predefined vars.

Comment: Wait, do I need to "init" each value ?

Comment: @WiseMan You can create the array of `mpfr_t` via an array declaration or with `malloc` (like any array in C). Then you need to "init" each `mpfr_t` element as usual. In short, allocating `mpfr_t` elements will allocate the structures (precision, sign, exponent, and significand pointer fields). Initializing a `mpfr_t` will allocate the significand (a.k.a. mantissa), whose minimum allocated size depends on the precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [GNU MPFR 4.0.2](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html), i found:

> The C data type for such objects is mpfr_t, internally defined as a one-element array of a structure (so that when passed as an argument to a function, it is the pointer that is actually passed), and mpfr_ptr is the C data type representing a pointer to this structure.

And at **5.1 initialization function**:

> An mpfr_t object must be initialized before storing the first value in it. The functions mpfr_init and mpfr_init2 are used for that purpose.

```
Function: void mpfr_init2 (mpfr_t x, mpfr_prec_t prec)
```

> Initialize x, set its precision to be exactly prec bits and its value to NaN. (Warning: the corresponding MPF function initializes to zero instead.)
>
> Normally, a variable should be initialized once only or at least be cleared, using mpfr_clear, between initializations. To change the precision of a variable which has already been initialized, use mpfr_set_prec. The precision prec must be an integer between MPFR_PREC_MIN and MPFR_PREC_MAX (otherwise the behavior is undefined).

```
Function: void mpfr_inits2 (mpfr_prec_t prec, mpfr_t x, ...)
```

> Initialize all the mpfr_t variables of the given variable argument va_list, set their precision to be exactly prec bits and their value to NaN. See mpfr_init2 for more details. The va_list is assumed to be composed only of type mpfr_t (or equivalently mpfr_ptr). It begins from x, and ends when it encounters a null pointer (whose type must also be mpfr_ptr).

One example:

```
{
  mpfr_t x, y;
  mpfr_init (x);                /* use default precision */
  mpfr_init2 (y, 256);          /* precision exactly 256 bits */
  …
  /* When the program is about to exit, do ... */
  mpfr_clear (x);
  mpfr_clear (y);
  mpfr_free_cache ();           /* free the cache for constants like pi */
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: thanks a lot ! Found a solution already, but it is based on what you wrote (I had the same thoughts).